# Get download link for file issued by Commerce File via PHP

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce, files

I have set up the Commerce Module on my website with the Commerce File contrib module, which is working fine. However, I would like to be able to display the links to the files that have been purchased on a seperate node. So is there any way that I can use PHP, or even tokens, to get the URL that enables the user to download the file for use in my own hyperlink on a custom node?

I think I've made that clear enough, but please don't hesitate to ask if you need me to clarify anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Commerce File 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @BojanZivanovic It's Commerce File 2.x. At the minute I do have quite an ugly workaround where I generate the download token by loading the file by id, and then prepending it to `/file/%fid/download?token=` but obviously that's not the best or most reliable so I would prefer a propper solution